# Libgdx: change ImageButton image on click

Tags: libgdx

In my game in Libgdx I want to change ImageButton image on click. I think this should be easy, but I have lost hours on this. :)

```
    public void show() {
        buttonSound = new ImageButton(skin.getDrawable("sound_off"));
        buttonSound.addListener(new onSoundListener());
}

    class  onSoundListener extends InputListener {

        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            buttonSound.setBackground(skin.getDrawable("btn_sound"));

        }
    }
```

This doesn't work. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found solution for my problem by setting `checked` image

```
ImageButton (Drawable imageUp, Drawable imageDown, Drawable imageChecked)
```

and then

```
    if (gameData.isSound())
        buttonSound.setChecked(false);
    else
        buttonSound.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: I really do appreciate when people get back to their questions and post the answer they found.